# NGINX on URL load static content

Tags: nginx, url, static, overriding

Having the following nginx configuration I try to load static content if url `/intern` is requested, but what I try it fails in 404. How can I properly setup nginx for this case?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/html/public;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
      include fastcgi_params;
      #try_files $uri /index.php =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass php:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
  
    location = /intern {
       autoindex on;
       root /var/www/html/public/back;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of the `root` directive, full path is appended to the root including the location part, whereas in case of the `alias` directive, only the portion of the path NOT including the location part is appended to the alias.

So for:

```
 location = /intern/ {
       autoindex on;
       root /var/www/html/public/back;
    }
```

nginx will create the final path to be:

`/var/www/html/public/back/intern/*`

Assuming you don't have the `intern` directory inside the `.../public/back/` directory, this will result in a 404 error.
If that's the case, you should use the `alias` directive. Where the location path is **dropped** before looking for the file at the said location.

try this:

```
location = /intern/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /var/www/html/public/back/;  # trailing slash is important here
    }
```

This should result in the path:

```
/var/www/html/public/back/*
```

Comment: Thanks for Feedback I tried with alias as you suggested but still can not map properly the directory as I'm getting 404.

Comment: Can you check/share the nginx error logs in the file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`?